# How to install JRE on Ubuntu

Tags: java, software-installation

I am currently using Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 64bit. I have never before installed software from source.

I want to install the java plugin for chrome for running applets and all. I presently need it for downloading youtube videos from keepvids. I downloaded the jre-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz file from oracle.

I used:

```
tar -xzvf jre-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz
cd jre1.7.0_55
./configure
```

But I get:

```
bash: /.configure: No such file or directory
```

The readme file there doesn't contain any information about installation only license info..

Can anyone help me how to install it correctly(i am pretty comfortable with the terminal) and ADD it to GOOGLE CHROME...What else do i have to do? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you are installing this way? Other options are here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Comment: I not yet know any alternative

Comment: Well there is a much simpler answer on that question, here: http://askubuntu.com/a/99522/15341

Comment: Nice! I've been using duinsoft.nl's not-so-Ubuntu-friendly repository for Java. Good to know!

Comment: Why you try to install from sources? Isn't `sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin` enough? BTW, the error message says `/.configure` no `./configure`, you sure is not a typo?

Answer (score 1):

there is a far easier way. And as a pretty new User to Ubuntu, your should not install anything outside the package-manager.

JRE is already included in the Ubuntu packages. So for installing JRE, go to your Synaptic and look for these packages:

```
default-jre
default-jre-headless
gjc-4.8-jre-lib
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm
openjdk-7-jre
openjdk-7-jre-headless
openjdk-7-jre-zero
```

install these packages and JRE will be installed. And as a pretty new user, you should keep in mind: never ever install anything outside the package-managerSynaptic. The other save alternative to install software, is the Ubuntu Softwarecenter.

This is already installed by default and you can find it in your menue.

Comment: I installed all the above mentioned packages except 'gjc-4.8-jre-lib'(i did not get it in synaptic package manager) but still the chrome applets are not running. Any thing i have to do to bring it to chrome?